# Windows 7 + Bind on Ubuntu - DNS keeps stopping

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, dns, bind

I have a Bind DNS server running from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server 64 bit. In there, I've setup some local A records for internal websites, e.g. wiki.domain.local.

Everything works fine, except that every so often (a few times a day), the DNS stops responding on client machines (running Windows 7). The only way I've found to fix it is to stop/start the dnscache service on the Windows machine. Sometimes if I just wait for a few minutes, the DNS will start to work again.

I've checked the Windows event log and can't see anything relevant. I've also had a look in the Bind logs and can't see anything there.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

I think I am having a similar issue

https://serverfault.com/questions/439791/ipv6-causing-issue-with-dns

I found that by modifying the network adapter it seemed to fix the issue temporarily. Also I am able to connect to the server through IP, just not DNS.

Restarting the DNS doesn't seem to help, seems like the fix comes from the client side, but presumably caused by an issue on the server side.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. For example, *what* did you modify in your network adapter?